# Compare MySQL result in PHP

Tags: php

I had retrieve some result from database and want to display the result separately.

If the pb_title is same as temp_title then put it togather in a red color div
else is pb_title is not same as temp_title then put it in grey color div

Here my tried code :

```
$select_brand = "SELECT * FROM tblProduct_Brand WHERE pb_display='display'";
$result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $select_brand);

if($result)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$pb_feature_image = substr(($row['pb_feature_image']),3);
$pb_logo = substr(($row['pb_logo']),3);         
$temp_result;
if($temp_result == $row["pb_title"])
{
    //if product brand title is same, put it in same area
    echo '<div style="padding:20px; background-color:red;">';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:340px;height:250px;vertical-align:top;">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_feature_image.'" width="100%" height="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:250px;padding-left:10px;">';
        echo '<div style="height:40px;width:80px;float:right">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_logo.'" width="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<a class="product-content">'.$row["pb_content"].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    $temp_result = $row["pb_title"];
}
else
{
    //if not same, put in another area
    echo '<div style="padding:20px; background-color:grey;">';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:340px;height:250px;vertical-align:top;">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_feature_image.'" width="100%" height="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:250px;padding-left:10px;">';
        echo '<div style="height:40px;width:80px;float:right">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_logo.'" width="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<a class="product-content">'.$row["pb_content"].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Any mistake about the code please correct me. 
Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you facing . ?

Comment: @Adeel I cant place the same pb_title result in the same div. Example if row1 title and row2 title is same, the result will display in red div box. And row 3 title is not same as row2 it will display in grey div box.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer about what you're trying to do.  The explanations so far make very little sense.

Comment: @user3663143 Let me get this right; you want to add all of the titles that match to the **same** div instead of creating a new div for each of them?

Comment: @Darren I have two div here with color RED and GREY. I want make all match title in RED div and not match title is GREY div.

Comment: @Darren My idea is if current title result is not match with previous title then separate it, and if is match put it together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp_result;
if($temp_result == $row["pb_title"])
```

Before checking the condition you should have assigned some value to $temp_result , but you haven't and you are comparing it anyway.

EDIT :

What I understand is that initially you have not set any value of $temp_result and it is always coming in your Else Block where you do'not assign `$temp_result = $row["pb_title"];` , So that it shoudl store the previous value , you only did it in the If Block , you need to place the same code in your else block too..

Simple Edit this section in your code

```
else
{
    //if not same, put in another area
    echo '<div style="padding:20px; background-color:grey;">';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:340px;height:250px;vertical-align:top;">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_feature_image.'" width="100%" height="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:250px;padding-left:10px;">';
        echo '<div style="height:40px;width:80px;float:right">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_logo.'" width="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<a class="product-content">'.$row["pb_content"].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    $temp_result = $row["pb_title"]; // added this to save previous result
}
```

Comment: Yes I did try before. Then the output is all result will show in red color div box mean

Comment: What this variable $temp_result should contain. ?

Comment: I want is initial row1 title is "A" and row2 title is "A" too. So put them in same red div. When loop to row3 and the title is "B", then will display in grey color div box.

Comment: $temp_result used to store the pb_title that is receive

Comment: can I make the "A" and the title result that I get from database? mean that IF current title is not match with previous title than separate.

Comment: I can't get it exactly , correct me if I am wrong .
You need to store the previous title you extracted from the Db then compare it with current title if it matches then show it in red box else grey box . ?

Comment: Yes..exactly what i want

Comment: @user3663143 I've edited my ans to show you what exactly do I mean , did it fixed your problem . ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes that you did something like this with the data you fetched from the sql query:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Which returns an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        'pb_title' => '',
        'pb_content' => '',
        //...etc
    ),
    //.....etc
)
```

Now assuming that I understand your question correctly, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$i = array();
$key = 'A';
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item['pb_title'] == $key) {
        $i['red'][] = $item;
    } else {
        $i['grey'][] = $item;
    }
}
```

Which gives you an array of `red` (*Matching*) and `grey` (*Not Matching*).

Which you can loop through and generate your `div`'s appropriately.
Something like this (***pseudo code***)

```
echo '<div style="padding:20px; background-color:red;">';
foreach($i['red'] as $row) {
    echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:340px;height:250px;vertical-align:top;">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_feature_image.'" width="100%" height="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:250px;padding-left:10px;">';
        echo '<div style="height:40px;width:80px;float:right">';
        echo '<img src="'.$logo.'" width="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<a class="product-content">'.$row["pb_content"].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/168627)

Comment: did have other way wihout using Array? Are we able to use if else statement to do that..?

Comment: @user3663143 are they **all** going to be in the same **1** div or have their own divs ?

Comment: They are going to their own div

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that programing should be effective for that you need to have following ideas:

1) Here you no need to use `if($result)` because when the sql results are true then only it will allow inside the condition

2) While programing try to avoid more `if else`  condition for making efficient.

```
<?php
$select_brand = "SELECT * FROM tblProduct_Brand WHERE pb_display='display'";
$result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $select_brand);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$pb_feature_image = substr(($row['pb_feature_image']),3);
$pb_logo = substr(($row['pb_logo']),3);         

$temp_result;

if($temp_result == $row["pb_title"]) { $style = 'style="padding:20px; background-color:red;"'; }
else { $style = ' style="padding:20px; background-color:grey;"'; }

    echo '<div '.$style.' >';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:340px;height:250px;vertical-align:top;">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_feature_image.'" width="100%" height="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:250px;padding-left:10px;">';
        echo '<div style="height:40px;width:80px;float:right">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pb_logo.'" width="100%"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<a class="product-content">'.$row["pb_content"].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    $temp_result = $row["pb_title"];
}


?>
```